# bakery algorithm, switching up the condition

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, distributed-systems, concurrency, synchronization

I'm currently studying the Bakery Algorithm.  I understand it for what it is but now I want to switch it up a bit.

If we changed the `<` in the 2nd `while()` loop to `≤` what exactly would happen?

My take:  I don't think it'll cause starvation but I think I'm wrong.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

```
do {      
    choosing[i] = true;       
    number[i] = max(number[0], number[1], …, number [n – 1])+1;       
    choosing[i] = false;       
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {           
        while (choosing[j]);            
        while ((number[j]!= 0) && (number[j],j) < (number[i],i)));       
    }       
    critical section number
    number[i] = 0; 
    remainder section
} while(1);
```

Comment: You could answer your own question by editing the TLA encoding of the algorithm (and proof). See [https://github.com/tlaplus/Examples]

Comment: And to save you some time, investigate what happens when j reaches i. After your change, it's impossible for process i to leave that loop. It may pay off to study the original formulation of the bakery algorithm rather than your butchered one.